# Merging shapefiles with attributes using PyQGIS?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, merge

I have some shapefiles. They are all the same kind of shape and all have the same attributes.

If I wanted to merge them manually the "Vector/Data management tools/merge shapefiles to one" works fine.

However, as per the question title, I'd like to do this using Python from a script.

I went hunting for the "merge shape files" in the hopes I could cobble it into my script but I couldn't find it.

I tried writing one myself iterating over the features and copying them into another layer as per the pyQGIS cookbook but lost the attributes along the way.

```
feature_list = inputlayer.getFeatures()
  for feature in feature_list:
    (res, outFeats) = outputlayer.dataProvider().addFeatures( [ feature ] )
```

I also tried writing a script using the iface copy features function with the same loss of attributes as a result.

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(importlayer)
importlayer.setSelectedFeatures(range(100))
#(there are exactly 100 features)
qgis.utils.iface.actionCopyFeatures().trigger()
iface.setActiveLayer( outputlayer )
outputlayer.startEditing()
qgis.utils.iface.actionPasteFeatures().trigger()
```

Can someone help me fix my code to retain the copied attributes or point me to a pyQGIS script to achieve this result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK here's the answer.
I have discovered the processing toolbox from which there was a simple solution: As per http://qgis.org/de/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

From the console you can get a list of all the algorithms available which contain the word "merge" by typing:

```
import processing
processing.alglist("merge")
```

Then you could find out how to use the most appropriate function with:

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")
```

Then simply use the algorithm in your script as follows:

```
processing.runalg("qgis:mergevectorlayers", layer1, layer2,"outputfilename.shp")
```

On the other hand *manually* merging shapes may still be useful. For those who still want to manually copy features from an input layer into some destination layer *with* attributes you need to first make sure the destination layer has those fields.

```
old_attribute_List = input_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
new_attribute_List=[]
for attrib in old_attribute_List:
  if destination_layer.fieldNameIndex(attrib.name())==-1:
    new_attribute_List.append(QgsField(attrib.name(),attrib.type()))
destination_layer_data_provider.addAttributes(new_attribute_List)
destination_layer.updateFields()
```

Then to manually copy over the features you can do:

```
destination_layer.startEditing()
cfeature = QgsFeature()
cfeatures=[]
xfeatures = input_layer.getFeatures()
for xfeature in xfeatures:
    xgeometry = xfeature.geometry()
    #GEOMETRY TRANSFORM GOES HERE IF DESTINATION CRS DIFFERS FROM INPUT CRS
    cfeature_Attributes=[]
    cfeature_Attributes.extend(xfeature.attributes())
    cfeature.setGeometry(xgeometry)
    cfeature.setAttributes(cfeature_Attributes)
    cfeatures.append(cfeature)
destination_layer_data_provider.addFeatures(cfeatures)
destination_layer_data_provider.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Note that now QgsVectorLayer has the `.pendingFields()` method which simplier to apply than the code above. See [pyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#add-features)

Comment: Note also the differences between `DataProvider.addFeatures()` and `QgsVectorLayer.addFeatures()` as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266278/qgsvectorlayer-vs-qgsvectordataprovider-for-addfeatures-function-in-qgis