# QgsVectorLayer vs QgsVectorDataProvider for addFeatures() function in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Has the addFeatures function moved between QgsVectorLayer and QgsVectorDataProvider?

Do both work? Is one deprecated. The apis do not provide that info. Nor does a google search.

Which is preferred and why?

What am I misunderstanding here? What is the situation that is changing which means I may need to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@MatthiasKuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn), one of the core developers of QGIS, has mentioned on his website [OPENGIS.ch](http://opengis.ch/2015/08/12/with-edit-layer/) to **avoid** using `dataProvider()` when adding features and instead do it directly on the layer (i.e. `layer.addFeature(...)`). He lists various reasons to avoid using the data provider:

- You cannot undo them easily.
- They generate one request per call what may reduce performance.
- They do not emit internal signals for map redraws and other refreshes of the user interface.
- They do not take uncommitted changes into account so the python changes will get overwritten by the user when he commits the layer changes.

---

You could also ask on the [QGIS Mailing List](https://lists.osgeo.org/listinfo/qgis-developer) where you could get a more explicit reason.

Comment: kind of handy to know - would be nice if the QGIS 3.16 Cookbook actually reflected this - it still refers to dataProvider.

Comment: You can make that change @nr_aus! :) https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/tree/master/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook

Comment: Yes this is true! i should do that for more stuff...... I guess my comment is more about the fact that a core developer has mentioned it on his website, as opposed to the official documentation. There could be a reason I suppose.